# Difference between two dates from database in php

Tags: php, yii

Dates are stored in the database in this format

```
month/day/year - hour:minute AM/PM
```

Example:

```
10/06/2014 - 07:25 AM
10/08/2014 - 09:30 AM
```

I want to find the difference between the dates in **x days y hours z minutes**.

Comment: do you have those spaces surrounding the hyphen `-` placed between date and time

Comment: yes, I think thats the main issue I am not able to find the correct output

Comment: try  [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

Comment: the coding is almost ready... what is the format you want... x days y hours **z days**?? clear me out...

Comment: Sorry, x days y hours z minuts

Comment: In your date `10/06/2014`, is in which format? **mm/dd/yyyy** or **dd/mm/yyyy**?

Comment: did i solve your problem?

Comment: i will be happy if you upvote my answer as useful... thank you @Rejin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date must be first formatted into a php date by using the function `date_create_from_format()` and the difference is found using the object oriented function `$interval->format()` with the formats specified with `%`.

Use this simple PHP code:

```
$format = "m/d/Y - h:i A";
$date1 = "10/06/2014 - 07:25 AM";
$date2 = "10/08/2014 - 09:30 AM";
$date1 = date_create_from_format($format, $date1);
$date2 = date_create_from_format($format, $date2);
$interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
echo $interval->format('%d days %h hours %i minutes');
```

This will give you are difference in dates in **x days y hours z minutes** as you want it to be.

And for your information, the **[date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** and **[inteval formats](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)** can be found in these links. Both of them are php manuals.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)`
If it's generic database query. But use date_diff if it's PHP operation.

In the case of your question, just put

```
DATEDIFF(m dd hh, "10/06/2014 -07:25AM", "10/08/2014 - 09:30 AM")
```

For a general database query